# Almond Bread vs Gain Based Bread

Tags: nutrition, nutrition-information

When almond bread breaks down in my body, do the carbohydrates turn into sugar?

I know that any grain based bread when breaking down in my body, will turn the carbohydrates into sugar in my body.

Comment: This is off topic for the site, but all carbohydrates (Except for non digestible fiber) break down to sugar (glucose).

Comment: Your right but I would say this is the most appropriate place out of all of the stack exchange sites. So almond flour would break down whatever carbohydrates it has into sugar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it breaks down according to the [question](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/When_almond_bread_breaks_down_in_your_body_do_the_carbohydrates_turn_into_sugar) I asked at answers.com.

"Yes, in general. However, not all can be used right away and so the excess will be stored in adipose tissue."